# Alternar um select e um datapicker

Tags: datepicker, html-select

Estou tentando implementar um campo que pode ser um `select` ou um `datepicker`.

Porém ao fazer a inserção do código na `<div>` causa a parada do funcionamento do `datepicker`. Deixo abaixo o código para quem puder me auxiliar.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#calendario" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    function desligar(){
       var divData = document.getElementById('data');
       divData.innerHTML="<p>Data: <select id='calendario'><option value='01/03/2018'>01/03/2018</option><option value='01/04/2018'>01/04/2018</option></select></p>";
    }
    function ligar(){
       var divData = document.getElementById('data');
       divData.innerHTML="<p>Data: <input type='text' id='calendario' /></p>";
    }
    </script>
    <title>Calendário jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='data'>
    <p>Data: <input type="text" id="calendario" /></p>
    </div>
<BR>
<BR>
<input type='button' onClick=ligar(); value='calendario'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='button' onClick=desligar(); value='select'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara com um simples checkbox "escondido" e CSS vc pode alternar entre um `input text` e um `input date`. Se quiser eu posto uma resposta com um exemplo pra vc ver se te serve.

Comment: ja fiz.. adorei a idéia.. as vezes pensar fora da caixa, é a melhor solução.. muito obrigado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta colocar `$( "#calendario" ).datepicker();` na função `ligar()`

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#calendario" ).datepicker();
});

    function desligar(){
       var divData = document.getElementById('data');
       divData.innerHTML="<p>Data: <select id='calendario'><option value='01/03/2018'>01/03/2018</option><option value='01/04/2018'>01/04/2018</option></select></p>";
    }
    function ligar(){
       var divData = document.getElementById('data');
       divData.innerHTML="<p>Data: <input type='text' id='calendario' /></p>";
        $( "#calendario" ).datepicker();
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Calendário jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='data'>
    <p>Data: <input type="text" id="calendario" /></p>
    </div>
<BR>
<BR>
<input type='button' onClick=ligar(); value='calendario'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='button' onClick=desligar(); value='select'>
 </body>
</html>
```